# How to keep npm start running forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, npm, proxy

I cloned a Git repository and I'm trying to run it with `npm start`.

This only works until I quit the terminal.

How do I get it to run, even after I quit the terminal?

I am using NGINX with Ubuntu 20.04, it runs on `http://localhost:3000` but I have a proxy set up with my own `example.com` pointing to that.

How can I keep it running continuously, so that even if I shut down the server and reboot it starts up again, similar to `systemd`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a process.
interrupt it.
send it background.
then detach it.
[How to detach process from terminal](https://serverfault.com/questions/34750/is-it-possible-to-detach-a-process-from-its-terminal-or-i-should-have-used-s#:%7E:text=9%20Answers&text=You%20can%20press%20ctrl%2Dz,the%20process%20from%20the%20terminal.)

you can also create a service to run `npm start` on boot